# XCom Value Not showing in Airflow MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

I'm running following script in MWAA and my local env.

```
from airflow import DAG, XComArg
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.redshift_sql import RedshiftSQLOperator
from airflow.models.connection import Connection
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator 
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
# from airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookHook
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import json
import requests
import time
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

default_args = {'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 21),
                'retries': 1,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
                'email_on_failure': False}

with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="load_dag", 
    schedule_interval="5 */2 * * 1-5",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 21), 
    tags=['load'],
    description='DAG to run datawarehouse.load',
    default_view='graph', #grid, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
    on_failure_callback = None,
    on_success_callback = None,
    catchup=False,
    # max_active_runs = 1,
    # concurrency=5
    ) as dag:
    person_duplicate_check = RedshiftSQLOperator(
        task_id = 'person_duplicate_check',
        sql="""
            with x as (
                select
                    contact_id,
                    count(1) as rows_count
                from person
                where contact_id is not null
                group by contact_id
            )
            select
                count(1) as id_count,
                count(case when rows_count > 1 then 1 end) as duplicate_id_count,
                sum(rows_count) as total_row_count,
                sum(case when rows_count > 1 then rows_count else 0 end) as duplicate_row_count
            from x;
        """,
        on_failure_callback = None,
        )
```

In my local I get Xcom value which looks like [[99796, 0, 99796, 0]]. However, when I run the same DAG in MWAA Airflow I get empty XCom. I have checked my Redshift Connection and it is working.

Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at this on my MWAA 2.4.3 and 2.2.2 environments running amazon-providers 6.0.0 and 2.4.0.

This is the version of the DAG I used (I was using the sample data you can optionally install when setting up a Redshift cluster)

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.redshift_data import RedshiftDataOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.redshift_sql import RedshiftSQLOperator

POLL_INTERVAL = 10
DAG_ID = 'example_redshift'
DB_LOGIN = 'awsuser'
DB_NAME = 'dev'
CLUSTER = "mwaa-redshift"

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID, 
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1), 
    tags=['load'],
    description='DAG to run datawarehouse.load',
    default_view='graph', #grid, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
    catchup=False
    ) as dag:
    run_query = RedshiftDataOperator(
        task_id='create_table_redshift_data',
        cluster_identifier=CLUSTER,
        database=DB_NAME,
        db_user=DB_LOGIN,
        sql="""
                        with x as (
                select
                    sellerid,
                    count(1) as rows_count
                from listing
                where sellerid is not null
                group by sellerid
            )
            select
                count(1) as id_count,
                count(case when rows_count > 1 then 1 end) as duplicate_id_count,
                sum(rows_count) as total_row_count,
                sum(case when rows_count > 1 then rows_count else 0 end) as duplicate_row_count
            from x;
        """,
        poll_interval=POLL_INTERVAL,
        await_result=True,
    )
```

I found that on the older provider it did not generate any xcom output, but in the newer provider it generated xcom output. That said, I could not get it to output the results of the query, only the Redshift query ID.

Are you using mwaa-local-runner and have you checked the provider package versions to see what you are using?

**update - 5th March**

I upgraded my mwaa 2.4.3 environment to have newer providers. Here is my requirements.txt file

```
--constraint "/usr/local/airflow/dags/updated-constraints.txt"
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==7.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==3.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.3.4
```

After my mwaa environment restarts and I check the provider versions.

[image]

And when I re-run the same DAG above, I now get what you are expecting.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the updated DAG I used with the same query:

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it on my end finally.

````
def table_duplication_call(tbl_name,sql):
    # print('Start of function', context)
    slack_token = BaseHook.get_connection('slack_default').password
    url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
#     print(url)
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {slack_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    data = {'channel': '#your_channel_name', 
            'mrkdwn':True,
            'text': f""":red_circle: Duplicates in {tbl_name} Table.
                    ```{sql}```
                """}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())


default_args = {'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 2),
                'retries': 1,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
                'email_on_failure': False}

with DAG(
    dag_id="load_dag", 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 2), 
    schedule_interval="15 */4 * * *", 
    tags=['some_tag'],
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup = False,
    description='Some description',
    default_view='graph', #grid, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
    on_failure_callback=None,
    on_success_callback=None,
    # on_failure_callback=send_email
    ) as dag:


    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'start',
        dag=dag,
    )
    
    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'end',
        dag=dag
    )


tbl_ls = ['table1','table2','table3']


def duplication_check_func():
        hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='redshift_default')
        for tbl in tbl_ls:
            sql = f"""
                                    select
                                            {tbl}.{tbl}_id duplicated_id,
                                            count({tbl}.{tbl}_id ) as cnt
                                        from
                                            datawarehouse.{tbl} 
                                        group by
                                            {tbl}_id 
                                        having
                                            cnt > 1;
                                    """
            results = hook.get_records(sql)
            if len(results)>0:
                table_duplication_call(tbl_name={tbl},sql=sql)
            else:
                None
        # return results
        

db_duplication_notification = PythonOperator(
task_id='db_duplication_notification',
python_callable=duplication_check_func,
dag=dag
)

start >> db_duplication_notification >> end
````